# Remove measured distribution from another distribution

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, signal-processing

Take a particle beam as an ensemble of many particles. Assume two independent random variables $X_\beta$ and $\delta$ that add up to the horizontal position $X$ of a particle:

$$
X = X_\beta + D_x \delta
$$

($D_x$ is a simple number, the "dispersion" function in beam dynamics.)

I have a horizontal measurement of the beam profile, $f_X$, and another measurement of the longitudinal momentum profile, $f_\delta$. I have normalised both to unity area and take them to be measurements of the probability density functions of $X$ and $\delta$:

[image: measured beam profiles in horizontal ($f_X$) and longitudinal ($f_\delta$) plane]

Now, I would like to determine the distribution / profile of $X_\beta$.

How do I have to proceed?

A first thought was to deconvolve $f_X$ with $f_{D_x\delta}$, after I interpolated both data sets to the same set of positions. Unfortunately, I failed with `scipy.signal.deconvolve`... I end up with an error quantity equal to the spectrum, i.e. I get nowhere.

If I convolve the two, I get an extension of $f_X$ by $f_{D_x\delta}$, as I'd expect:

[image: convolution of the horizontal and longitudinal profile measurements]

(via `numpy.convolve(f_x, f_Dxdelta, 'same')` where both arrays have the same length and are w.r.t. the same positions)

I'd like to do the opposite now and 'remove' instead of 'add' the dispersive part. Or am I gone in the completely wrong direction?

One more possibly important information: I expect $X_\beta$ to have a normal distribution as opposed to $\delta$. I would like to extract the corresponding standard deviation of $X_\beta$ from $f_X$.

Thanks for your help,
Adrian

PS: I have asked the same question in the physics stack exchange forum and I've been suggested to ask your community :-)
( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224671/remove-measured-distribution-from-another-distribution )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going down a rocky road with the deconvolution, a possible approach is to plug the assumed Gaussian distribution for $X_\beta$ into a convolution with the PDF of $D_x\delta$, the above $f_{D_x\delta}$. The resulting curve can then be made to fit the measured profile with an iterative algorithm varying $\sigma_{x_\beta}$, the sought standard deviation of the assumed Gaussian distribution.

I got reasonable results with this method. Nonetheless, I'm open for your suggestions and other, possibly better approaches... :-) Thank you.